# Why there no Sender address mentioned in newTransaction() function?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have doubt regarding the newTransaction() function in the transaction.go file in go-ethereum. Why there is no mention of sender's address in the newTransaction() function? From where does it get sender's address?

Here is the code:

```
func newTransaction(nonce uint64, to common.Address, amount, gasLimit,gasPrice big.Int, data []byte) *Transaction {
    if len(data) > 0 {
       data = common.CopyBytes(data)
    }
    d := txdata{
            AccountNonce: nonce,
            Recipient: to,
            Payload: data,
            Amount: new(big.Int),
            GasLimit: new(big.Int),
            Price: new(big.Int),
            V: new(big.Int),
            R: new(big.Int),
            S: new(big.Int),
    }
    if amount != nil {
        d.Amount.Set(amount)
    }
    if gasLimit != nil {
       d.GasLimit.Set(gasLimit)
    }
    if gasPrice != nil {
       d.Price.Set(gasPrice)
    }

return &Transaction{data: d}
}
```

Comment: You'd better ask on github than here I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender's address is recovered by the receiver from the transaction signature (`V`, `R` and `S` above), and the hash of the transaction data, using the ECDSARECOVER() function.  This is in fact how transactions are authenticated - if a valid address results from this, then that is the address of the sender/signer of the transaction.

Details are in the [Yellow Paper](http://yellowpaper.io/) appendix F.